# Not getting content in every creative. Urn:li:share:xxxxxxxxxx Only id is available in some blocks. how to get that missing data?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am calling you to bring all the creatives of linkedin using https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAccounts/xxxxxxxx/creatives?&intendedStatuses=(value:List(ACTIVE,PAUSED,ARCHIVED,CANCELED,DRAFT,PENDING_DELETION,REMOVED))&isTotalIncluded=false&leadgenCreativeCallToActionDestinations=List()&q=criteria&sortOrder=ASCENDING . I am getting data. I want the description of the creative which is coming in the content field. But not available for all creatives.

Not getting content(description,headline) in every creative. Urn:li:share:xxxxxxxxxx Only id is available in some blocks

```
 {
            "servingHoldReasons": [
                "CAMPAIGN_END_DATE_HOLD",
                "CAMPAIGN_STOPPED",
                "CAMPAIGN_TOTAL_BUDGET_HOLD"
            ],
            "lastModifiedAt": 1656577027000,
            "lastModifiedBy": "urn:li:system:0",
            "content": {
                "reference": "urn:li:share:xxxxxx"
            },
            "createdAt": 1553004550000,
            "isTest": false,
            "createdBy": "urn:li:unknown:0",
            "review": {
                "status": "APPROVED"
            },
            "isServing": false,
            "campaign": "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:xxxx",
            "id": "urn:li:sponsoredCreative:xxxx",
            "intendedStatus": "ACTIVE",
            "account": "urn:li:sponsoredAccount:xxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "servingHoldReasons": [
                "CAMPAIGN_END_DATE_HOLD",
                "CAMPAIGN_STOPPED",
                "CAMPAIGN_TOTAL_BUDGET_HOLD"
            ],
            "lastModifiedAt": 1553602992000,
            "lastModifiedBy": "urn:li:unknown:0",
            "content": {
                "follow": {
                    "description": {
                        "preApproved": "VISIT_COMPANY"
                    },
                    "logo": "urn:li:image:C510BAQFQp_YvPUkSZQ",
                    "showMemberProfilePhoto": true,
                    "organizationName": "Bulwark Systems",
                    "headline": {
                        "preApproved": "GROW_YOUR_BUSINESS_INSIGHTS"
                    },
                    "callToAction": "VISIT_ORGANIZATION_COMPANY_PAGE"
                }
            },
            "createdAt": 1553599625000,
            "isTest": false,
            "createdBy": "urn:li:unknown:0",
            "review": {
                "status": "APPROVED"
            },
            "isServing": false,
            "campaign": "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:xxx",
            "id": "urn:li:sponsoredCreative:xxxx",
            "intendedStatus": "ACTIVE",
            "account": "urn:li:sponsoredAccount:xxxx"
        }
```

Is there any api available for getting list of creative details which contains all info like creative name, discription,image url ?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue, but I found that the API route for content of posts, is a different one. I think it should be made available through the same route, but to bad.

Anyway, You can find the answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2023-10&tabs=http#batch-get-posts

Lets say your share URN is urn:li:share:123456789. You should first encode the  colons, then call this:

```bash
let config = {
  method: 'get',
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  url: 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts/urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A123456789',
  headers: { 
    'LinkedIn-Version': '202310', 
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0', 

  ... and the rest is all default.
```

Be aware of the following when using the LinkedIn Ads API:

- URNs should always be encoded
- The path should sometimes start with /rest/adAccounts/{{YOUR ID}}/... and sometimes just /rest/...
- Always include LinkedIn-Version and X-Restli-Protocol-Version in the headers

Good luck!